# Visual studio error CS1503 at compile time passing an instance object from project A to project B

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I'm writing a c# class on a Console project to test a public method from "Plugins" .dll.
The public method requires an object instance (of type IMessageSenderProvider) from the "Sender" .dll.

I added the "Sender" .dll reference on the test project using alias, I instantiated the IMessageSenderProvider object and then I passed it to the "Plugins" .dll public method to test.

During compile time I'm facing the error

> CS1503 "cannot convert from 'Sender.IMessageSenderProvider [C:\myPath\src\Sender\bin\Debug\Sender.dll]' to 'Sender.IMessageSenderProvider [C:\myPath\src\Plugins\bin\Debug\Plugins.dll]'

How can I fix the error?

Comment: You probably have two `IMessageSenderProvider.cs` files (one in each project). Declare the interface only once, otherwise they will be considered being two different interfaces, despite them having the same name.

Comment: Hi Olivier, IMessageSenderProvider.cs file is defined only once on the "Sender" dll.

Comment: Then maybe the one in `C:\myPath\src\Plugins\bin\Debug\Plugins.dll` has been built against another version. Rebuild everything.

Comment: the version is the same. The particular thing is that Plugins.dll is signed and it use ILMerge. The "sender.dll" is referenced on Plugin.dll as "global" and "Copy local = true".